Is lxdbr0 installed by default on wsl2 ubuntu distributions?
I'm trying to set up lxd and the lxd init command tells me that lxdbr0 bridged network is already installed. I'm trying to figure out where this is coming from.
I'm on a Windows 11 laptop, doing some experiments. I install a clean Ubuntu vm via wsl --install Ubuntu-22.04. I then install net-tools so I have access to the ifconfig command. This command shows lxdbr0!
I have not installed lxd or lxc and I confirm this by trying these commands. dpkg -l|grep lxd and snap list|grep lxd show nothing. Oddly, dmesg|grep lxd does show lots of results and this is the output of systemctl|grep lxd:
systemctl | grep lxd
  sys-devices-virtual-net-lxdbr0.device
                                                    loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxdbr0
  sys-subsystem-net-devices-lxdbr0.device
                                                    loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/net/devices/lxdbr0

How is lxdbr0 getting installed? I'd like to stick to default values for lxd init as much as possible and this is throwing a wrench in my setup.
I just want to create a large number of virtual ubuntu boxes and it seems that lxd containers are the most efficient path. I want these boxes to be able to access the web and access each other so I can experiment with various clustering software. I'm a software engineer, not a network guy or an admin so I don't care about why this is happening, just how to get past it and get my containers up and running.
